# How to create a personalised bucket column from Pandas cut() command with the auto-generated categories and bins?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a Pandas DataFrame with multiple columns. One of them is the `year`. From this column I want to create a new one with categorical values (I guess the therm is buckets), having the buckets auto-generated. It should result in something like that:

```
year_gr         year    other_cols
A (1909 - 1917) 1911    abc
B (1921 - 1930) 1923    def
C (1932 - 1941) 1935    ghi
```

I manage to create something close to it by:

```
year_gr = pd.cut(df.year, 10, labels=[
   'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'])
df['year_gr'] = year_gr

df.head()

year_gr year    other_cols
A       1911    abc
B       1923    def
C       1935    ghi
```

But how do I concatenate the rages generated automatically by `pd.cut` to my `year_gr` variable?
I saw we can add the parameter `retbins=True` in the `cut` command to extract the bins, but I didn't manage to make use of it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.cut results in a categorie object populated by interval objects. We use their .left and .right attributes to create the specified strings.

```
    import numpy as np, pandas as pd
    import string

    # test data:
    df=pd.DataFrame({"year":[1911,1923,1935,1911],"other_cols":["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]})
  Out:
           year other_cols
    0  1911        abc
    1  1923        def
    2  1935        ghi
    3  1911        jkl

    #create the intervals:
    cats=pd.cut(df.year,10)

    Out: cats.dtypes.categories
    IntervalIndex([(1910.976, 1913.4], (1913.4, 1915.8], (1915.8, 1918.2],...

    # char generator:
    gchar=(ch for ch in string.ascii_uppercase)
    dlbls= { iv:next(gchar) for iv in cats.dtypes.categories } #EDIT1
    # get the intervals and convert them to the specified strings:
    df["year_gr"]=[ f"{dlbls[iv]} ({int(np.round(iv.left))} - {int(np.round(iv.right))})" for iv in cats ] #EDIT1
   Out:
          year other_cols          year_gr
    0  1911        abc  A (1911 - 1913)
    1  1923        def  B (1921 - 1923)
    2  1935        ghi  C (1933 - 1935)
    3  1911        jkl  A (1911 - 1913)

    # align the columns:
    df= df.reindex(["year_gr","year","other_cols"], axis=1)
   Out:
               year_gr  year other_cols
    0  A (1911 - 1913)  1911        abc
    1  B (1921 - 1923)  1923        def
    2  C (1933 - 1935)  1935        ghi
    3  A (1911 - 1913)  1911        jkl
```

Comment: Thanks! It almost worked, but when I have multiple years in the same group, it's getting different letters. (and overflowing the gchars in the for, throwing an `StopIteration: ` error.
`----> 8 df["year_gr"] = [f"{next(gchar)} ({int(np.round(iv.left))} - {int(np.round(iv.right))})" for iv in cats]`
Without the `gchar` works though. I guess we need to add a `if` condition there to add the letters to one of the 10 categories.

Comment: You can reproduce the categories problem by:
`df=pd.DataFrame({"year":[1911,1912,1923,1935,1936,1946,2001,2003,2017,1984,1986],"other_cols":["abc","def","ghi","asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf"]})`
and the `StopIteration` error, just triplicate the number of lines.

Comment: @Bruno Ambrozio You are right! I edited the code above, created a dictionary ('dlbls') and use it for building the "year_gr" column. It seems too complicated, but I have no other idea.

Comment: nice! You did it. Thanks man! :)
```
df["year_gr"].count()
Out:
6168

df["year_gr"].unique()
Out: 
[H (1985 - 1995), D (1941 - 1952), B (1920 - 1931), G (1974 - 1985), A (1909 - 1920), F (1963 - 1974), E (1952 - 1963), C (1931 - 1941), J (2006 - 2017), I (1995 - 2006)]
Categories (10, object): [H (1985 - 1995), D (1941 - 1952), B (1920 - 1931), G (1974 - 1985), ..., E (1952 - 1963), C (1931 - 1941), J (2006 - 2017), I (1995 - 2006)]
```

Comment: Btw - do you know how to find out the best fit to the bins number? I'm using 10 because `df["year_of_birth"].max()-df["year_of_birth"].min()` results in `108`, thus arbitrary I decided by 10 groups... Wondering if there's a more smart way to do that, as my dataset can be unbalanced... Anyway - Perhaps this is a question for another post :)